# No network working in elementary os 6

Tags: networking, internet

I installed elementary is today and my wired network was working well, after installing nvidia drivers When I restarted I was not able to connect to my network. And wired and wireless options disappeared.
[image: see this image]

I am kinda new to Linux please help.

Comment: A little more information will be needed. Could you [edit] your question to include the Terminal output of the following commands: (1) `sudo lshw -c network` (2) sudo lsusb`. This will show information about your hardware. With this, it may be possible to answer your question 

Comment: Sorry now I have switched to Ubuntu as my work was pending to do. I got to know the problem was caused due to nvidia drivers.